# Logging task relationships in Celery

Tags: python, celery

If I have a signature that contains a complex structure of subtasks (e.g. below), is there a way of logging all the relationships between the tasks such that I could recreate the DependencyGraph at a later date?

e.g.

```
complex_task = group(task1 | task2 | group(task3, task4, task5 | task6), task7, task8)
```

Maybe I could capture the Ids of all the tasks and their parent task Ids, and log them? Can I do this in a generic way? e.g. something in task_postrun or in a Task baseclass?

My real objective here is, if there is a failure in one of the subtasks, easily tell where it occurred (hopefully by displaying the task structure graphically e.g. with [graphviz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate `DependencyGraph` from the result of your task.

```
In [4]: task_result = some_complex_task()

In [5]: task_result.parent.parent.graph
Out[5]: 285fa253-fcf8-42ef-8b95-0078897e83e6(1)
            463afec2-5ed4-4036-b22d-ba067ec64f52(0)
        872c3995-6fa0-46ca-98c2-5a19155afcf0(2)
            285fa253-fcf8-42ef-8b95-0078897e83e6(1)
            463afec2-5ed4-4036-b22d-ba067ec64f52(0)
```

You can convert these graphs to dot file:

```
In[22]:  with open('graph.dot', 'w') as fh:
   ...:     res.parent.parent.graph.to_dot(fh)
```

For more, check out [documentation](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#graphs).

**Example**
Let's print task names for a task.

*task_list.py:*

```
from celery import Celery, chain
celery_app = Celery('my_tasks', broker='amqp://', backend='amqp://')

@celery_app.task()
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@celery_app.task()
def sub(x, y):
    return x - y

c = chain(add.s(3, 4), sub.s(2))
```

SubTask names for Task c:

```
In [62]: r=c()

In [63]: r.parent.graph
Out[63]: 
d11c0076-a4e4-4e84-b26b-9b689860baa5(0)
68ba78cf-7e6c-4735-9173-2349da541b28(1)
     d11c0076-a4e4-4e84-b26b-9b689860baa5(0)

In [64]: r.graph
Out[64]: d11c0076-a4e4-4e84-b26b-9b689860baa5(0)

In [65]: while r:
   ....:     print(r.task_name)
   ....:     r = r.parent
   ....:     
task_list.sub
task_list.add
```

Comment: Is it also possible to get all the task ids out of the graph object so that I can log them?

Comment: @TomFerguson Yes, you can. I have added new example above.